# Batch file check if a variable is defined and its value

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
if /*some condition*/ set myvar=1


if defined myvar (
  if %myvar% equ 1 (
    echo Hurray
  )
)
```

However, I am getting the error `1 was not expected at this time`. With echo on, it prints `if equ 1 (`, where the error occurred. Please advice how to solve this.

Comment: `if "%myvar%" equ "1"` should work; if `%myvar%` contains a white-space or another token separator `,` `;` `=`, or if it contains other special characters like `^` `&` `<` `>` `|`, you will receive an error without the `""`; if it contains `"`, you cannot avoid an error unless you use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced `/*some condition*/` with `1==1`:

```
@echo off
if 1==1 set myvar=1
if defined myvar (
  if %myvar% equ 1 (
    echo Hurray
  )
)
```

This works perfectly. So the error must be somewhere inside your condition. I guess aschipfl's right about the missing `delayed expansion`. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if /*some condition*/ set myvar=1
if defined myvar (
  if !myvar! equ 1 (
    echo Hurray
  )
)
```

Add enabledelayedexpansion and surround your variables with `!...!` instead of `%...%`.

Comment: What does !var! do?

Comment: Variables are being expanded at interpretation time. This means your script is processed and all values are set to the vars. If the variable changes it's value and the new value can't be calculated at the start of your script (e.g. when it depends on the user's input, when it is inside an if or a for construct) the value won't change it's value. To make the value be "recalculated" you have to surround it with !...!. This is called delayed expansion.

Comment: But in this case the variable has already been set prior to the beginning of the code block, so delayed expansion is not needed. Aschipfl identified the true source of the problem in his question comment - spaces (or other token delimiters) within the value that are tripping up the IF parser. Easily solved by adding quotes around both sides of the comparison. Use of delayed expansion also avoids the problem, but for a reason completely different than what you have explained.

Comment: It's about the `if /*some condition*/ set myvar=1` block. It seems like the condition can't be evaluated because missing delayedexpansion as the code terminates properly with any normal condition. So one can conclude that delayedexpansion is needed to evaluate the condition which means that myvar depends on a a condition needing delayedexpansion so myvar will also need delayedexpansion which means you will need !myvar! instead of %myvar%.